# How can you sum multiple ID's into single Categories?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So the problem that I'm facing is, I'm trying to sum multiple things into single Categories. What I mean by this is take the below as an example:

[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 1 (Data)
The one thing I'm focused on currently is the Placement section with the ID's (Numbers) within the string.

[image: Sheet 2]

Sheet 2 (Lookup Sheet with Category) To be able to match ID's to Categories

[image]

Totals that I would like to get, I have tried SUMIFS such as:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet1!$B:$B,"*"&Sheet2!$A:$A&"*",Sheet2!$B:$B,$F2)
```

But that only sums up the first section, 5000+1000 = 6000, when it should be 20500. I think I'm close to the answer but not sure how to grab all of it within Excel or if there is another formula that would work better.

Please let me know if anything needs to be explained further and thank you in advance,

-Maykid

Comment: Why don't you just add a column to `Sheet1` to do the `Vlookup` for `ID` to get the `Category`. `=VLOOKUP(INT(MID(B2,FIND("_",B2)+1,4)),Sheet2!F$2:G$4,1,FALSE)` Then insert subtotals based on the `Category`. This assumes that the `ID` is always 4 characters.

Comment: @WEI_DBA The `ID's` in what I work with can vary, the above was just an example piece. But, are you stating to have `Category` within `Sheet1` to be identified, then do a `SUM` process to match the `Category` instead of based on `ID`?

Comment: If that would be easier to match in the `SUMIFS` function, then yes.

Comment: @WEI_DBA if I was going to go that route, would it be simply a `INDEX MATCH` Formula to be able to grab the audience number within the `Placement` Column then match it to the `Category` or what would that look like?

Comment: It would be the `Vlookup`, but the `Mid` function would have to look for the second underscore for the ending of the number. That would pull the `Category` into a column and then you can do subtotals on that `Category` to get what you want.

Comment: @WEI_DBA So I was able to come up with a formula to grab the ID from the string, but when I try to add in a `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX MATCH` it comes out with a `#NA` error. The code I came up with is, `=MID($B2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B2,"_",CHAR(1),1))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B2,"_",CHAR(1),2))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B2,"_",CHAR(1),1))-1)` But when I try to add in `Category` into it, it throws errors out. Any idea's?

Comment: Post your `Vlookup` please. Did you convert the `Mid()` function to an `INT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of WEI_DBA, I first created an ID column, then off of that created a Category column using the following code:

ID Column

```
=MID($B3,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B3,"_",CHAR(1),1))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B3,"_",CHAR(1),2))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B3,"_",CHAR(1),1))-1)
```

Then the Category Column:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8,MATCH(--$D2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8,0))
```

Then I found a way to put the two together and the reason for the error I was getting was because it the ID wasn't converted back to a number within Excel. I used the following Column to get just the Category column:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8,MATCH(--MID($B2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B2,"_",CHAR(1),1))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B2,"_",CHAR(1),2))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B2,"_",CHAR(1),1))-1),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8,0))
```

Then from there I was able to do a SUMIFS function to get the totals such as:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$G:$G,M18)
```

Then I was able to get the SUM of each Category. Much appreciated WEI_DBA for brainstorming!

-Maykid